# How to remove URL from list of tweets?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, python-re

I have a list of tweets that looks like this:

```
tweet_list = ['Justin Reid has been non-existent today No showed after talking Send him back to Houston where he clearly belongs', '❌Refer to Native Americans as “ immigrants ” ‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️ https //twitter.com/VzYgzn4JDi', 'RepJeffries Yeah think  about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal immigrants DM me if agree', 'RepJeffries Division is way up the stock market is way down people are losing lots of money the Congress is getting more corrupt our country is being invaded by illegal immigrants', 'Russian invaders marching to their deaths SlavaUkraïni https //twitter.com/6RM5IGrT6i']
```

And I want to remove all URLs and non-ASCII characters.

I have tried to do the following:

```
# Clean tweets
def clean_tweets(tweet):
    if type(tweet) == np.float:
        return ""
    temp = tweet.lower()
    temp = re.sub("'", "", temp) # to avoid removing contractions in english
    temp = re.sub("@[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
    temp = re.sub("#[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
    temp = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', temp)        # Remove URL!
    temp = re.sub('[()!?]', ' ', temp)
    temp = re.sub('\[.*?\]',' ', temp)
    temp = re.sub("[^a-z0-9]"," ", temp)
    temp = temp.split()
    # temp = [w for w in temp if not w in stopwords]
    temp = " ".join(word for word in temp)
    return temp

# Clean each tweet in tweet_list
cleaned_tweets = []
for entry in tweet_list:
    cleaned_tweets.append(clean_tweets(entry))

# print tweet before cleaning
print(tweet_list[1])

# print tweet after cleaning
print(cleaned_tweets[1])
```

Before the cleaning method was applied, `tweets_list[1]` looked like this : `❌Refer to Native Americans as “ immigrants ” ‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️ https //twitter.com/VzYgzn4JDi`

And after, it looks like this:
`refer to native americans as immigrants twitter com vzygzn4jdi`

So I'm confused as to why the entire link was not deleted. Is there a way to remove the entire link, regardless of where it occurs in the tweet?

Example output should be a list of tweets without non-ASCII characters or URLs or punctuation:

`refer to native americans as immigrants`

(Apologies for the offensive Tweets)

Comment: can you please add output what you want??

Comment: Example output: ```refer to native americans as immigrants```

Comment: What do you want to do with numbers like in this sentence : `about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal` ?

Comment: I would like to leave the numbers in. I only want to remove non-ASCII characters, URLs, and punctuation.

Comment: @display_name_1 your regex is simply removing the http instead of removing the entire link. try this `(?:https?)\s\S+`

Comment: Yes! this worked. Thank you very much. If you would like to post this as an answer, I will accept it. @Ramesh

Comment: @display_name_1 you want to clean `SlavaUkraïni` as `SlavaUkrani`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
tweet_list = ['Justin Reid has been non-existent today No showed after talking Send him back to Houston where he clearly belongs', '❌Refer to Native Americans as “ immigrants ” ‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️ https //twitter.com/VzYgzn4JDi', 'RepJeffries Yeah think  about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal immigrants DM me if agree', 'RepJeffries Division is way up the stock market is way down people are losing lots of money the Congress is getting more corrupt our country is being invaded by illegal immigrants', 'Russian invaders marching to their deaths SlavaUkraïni https //twitter.com/6RM5IGrT6i']


l=[]

for a in tweet_list:
  a= a.lower()

  b = re.sub(r'https //\S+', '', a)
  result= re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ ]', '', b)

  l.append(result)
print(l)
```

Output

```
['justin reid has been nonexistent today no showed after talking send him back to houston where he clearly belongs', 'refer to native americans as  immigrants   ', 'repjeffries yeah think  about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal immigrants dm me if agree', 'repjeffries division is way up the stock market is way down people are losing lots of money the congress is getting more corrupt our country is being invaded by illegal immigrants', 'russian invaders marching to their deaths slavaukraïni']
```

I think this way you can remove url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

- Have converted to lowercase as per your example
- have kept numbers as requested
- removed urls as requested
- kept foreign characters eg. `slavaukraïni`
- cleaned up any replicate spaces left over

### Code:

```
import re

tweet_list = ['Justin Reid has been non-existent today No showed after talking Send him back to Houston where he clearly belongs', 
              '❌Refer to Native Americans as “ immigrants ” ‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️ https //twitter.com/VzYgzn4JDi', 
              'RepJeffries Yeah think  about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal immigrants DM me if agree', 
              'RepJeffries Division is way up the stock market is way down people are losing lots of money the Congress is getting more corrupt our country is being invaded by illegal immigrants', 
              'Russian invaders marching to their deaths SlavaUkraïni https //twitter.com/6RM5IGrT6i']

new_tweetlist = []
for tweet in tweet_list:
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    temp = re.sub(r'https.*|(?![0-9À-ÿa-z\s]).','', tweet)
    temp = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', temp)
    new_tweetlist.append(temp)
    
for tweet in new_tweetlist:
    print(tweet)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
justin reid has been nonexistent today no showed after talking send him back to houston where he clearly belongs
refer to native americans as immigrants 
repjeffries yeah think about who got the jobs 5 millions illegal immigrants dm me if agree
repjeffries division is way up the stock market is way down people are losing lots of money the congress is getting more corrupt our country is being invaded by illegal immigrants
russian invaders marching to their deaths slavaukraïni
```